# ActiveAndroid Update and Delete from table

Tags: android, activeandroid

Hi guys so I'm trying to test how to use databases in android as part of one of my classes, but I'm pretty new to both so most help I found online has gone a bit over my head.

I was wondering how exactly do I update, and delete from the table. Currently I have:

```
    wk item = new wk();
            item.name = "okay1";
            item.save();
```

And that adds an item fine.

and in my database it has

```
public class wk extends Model {
    Table(name = "ToDoItems")
    @Column(name = "Name")
```

But I try to run

```
new Delete().from(wk.class).where("Name = ?",2).execute();
```

Which I'm assuming deletes the value at 2 in the database of Name, but instead it seems to do nothing? I have tried

```
new Delete().from(wk.class).execute();
```

Which does definitely delete my table so I know it can delete, but I just want to delete one value.

Pretty much I want to be able to delete that okay1 value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay I found the answer I had for deleting which is

```
new Delete().from(wk.class).where("Name = ?","okay1").execute();
```

And works perfect for me now.

Comment: How to delete rows for Boolean condition

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [documentation of ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Saving-to-the-database#deleting-records), you can as well delete your object statically :

```
public static void delete(MyClass obj){
    obj.delete();
}
```

It can be useful, especially if you are using a DAO design pattern.

Comment: is it possible to delete all data from specific table ? I don't see any thing like that in docs.

Comment: Mahen, I am pretty sure you can delete all data from a specific table with the query builder without providing any "which" statement: 
new Delete().from(Item.class).execute();

Answer (score 0):

if your condition return single value

```
new Delete().from(modelclassname.class).where("OnBasisof=?",value).executesingle();
```

if your condition return multiple  value

```
new Delete().from(modelclassname.class).where("OnBasisof=?",value).execute();
```